# Database parole italiane con accento

Tags: single-words, resources, accents

Buongiorno,

Sto cercando un database di parole italiane che contenga anche informazioni sull'accento tonico - vorrei provare a raggruppare assieme le parole che rimano, e senza accento è impossibile. Con l'accento almeno ci si può provare...

Ho trovato un po' di risorse online dove l'accento tonico manca, le posso comunque lasciare qui se qualcuno dovesse averne bisogno:

- https://github.com/mircomacrelli/italian-dictionary
- https://github.com/titoBouzout/Dictionaries
- https://github.com/pazqo/scalaWords

Sapete se ci sono risorse del genere in giro? Grazie!

Comment: Non mi è molto chiaro cosa tu stia cercando e perché, comunque se su Google scrivi cerchi lista  parole con accento tonico sicurante trovi del materiale utile.

Comment: Grazie mille per l'invito ad usare un motore di ricerca, non avrei disturbato la community senza aver prima cercato (senza successo) su Google. L'idea è di avere una lista di parole dove è anche segnato l'accento tonico, e.g. al posto di "ricerca" uno troverebbe "ricèrca", e per "pesca" ci sarebbero due elementi "pèsca" e "pésca"

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE! Puoi vedere tutti gli accenti tonici nel [*Dizionario d’ortografia e pronuncia*](http://www.dizionario.rai.it/sfoglia.aspx?treeID=7) e anche su altri dizionari che trovi nella nostra [pagina di risorse online sulla lingua italiana](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/123/707).

Comment: Se ho ben capito, l'OP cerca un singolo file in un formato di solo testo o poco più con un elenco di parole italiane (anche le forme flesse?) munite di accento tonico. Giusto?

Comment: La cosa che stai cercando (raggruppare le parole per rima), si chiama *rimario*. Ce ne sono numerosi disponibili in commercio, anche se non ne conosco uno di elettronico in un formato facilmente utilizzabile.

Comment: @DaG sì, esatto! Esattamente quello. Sulle forme flesse ora non voglio fare lo schizzinoso, chiaramente più ce n'è e meglio è

Comment: @DenisNardin Grazie, in effetti voglio costruire una sorta di rimario... però sospettavo che non fosse facile trovarne uno in formato elettronico